# Create Custom mapping type in Elasticsearch 7.3.2 using node js

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

When I am doing custom mapping using kibana its working properly but when I am doing the same thing in my node program its showing mapper parsing exception.
Reason:Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:tags(custom mapping name) 
Because in kibana i am able to use include_type_name =true but in my node program it is not available.

````
        var name = req.body.templatename;
        var index_patterns = req.body.index_patterns;
        console.log(index_patterns);
        const opts: IndicesPutTemplateParams = {
            name: name,
            body: {
                index_patterns: [index_patterns],
                settings: {
                    analysis: {
                        filter: {
                            autocomplete_filter: {
                                type: "edge_ngram",
                                min_gram: 1,
                                max_gram: 20
                            }
                        },
                        analyzer: {
                            autocomplete: {
                                type: "custom",
                                tokenizer: "standard",
                                filter: [
                                    "lowercase",
                                    "autocomplete_filter"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                mappings: {
                    tags: {
                        properties: {
                            name: {
                                type: "text",
                                analyzer: "autocomplete",
                                search_analyzer: "standard"
                            },
                            normalized: {
                                type: "text"
                            },
                            status: {
                                type: "text"
                            },
                            createdat: {
                                type: "date"
                            },
                            updatedat: {
                                type: "date"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        try {
            esClient.indices.putTemplate(opts).then((data: any) => {
               return res.json({
                   data
               });
                console.log(data);
              }).catch((err: any) => {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).json({
                    err
                })
            });     
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).json({
                error
            })
        }
    }```
````

Answer (score 1):

As Per [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html) you need to give include_type_name as

```
client.indices.putTemplate({
  name: string,
  include_type_name: boolean,  ---> 
  order: number,
  create: boolean,
  timeout: string,
  master_timeout: string,
  flat_settings: boolean,
  body: object                -> mapping object
})
```

Or you can drop mapping name tags from mapping

```
  mappings: {
                    tags: {  ---> remove
```

Comment: This is not useful.

Comment: What is the issue?. Please elaborate

Comment: when i am using include_type_name in my typescript file its showing error because there is no include_type_name parameter in putmapping.

Comment: You can remove include type name. Mapping structure is like below mappings: { properties:{}}. If you are giving include type name then you need to define mapping like below mappings: { “type_name”:{ “properties”:{}}}. Type name is only for backward compatibility, you don’t need to give it in mapping or command